# Python, Using wxPython to get multiple input from user

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, input, wxpython, input-field

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532827/using-wxpython-to-get-input-from-user) I found out how to ask the user for an input using wxPython. But how can I ask for multiple information at the same time?

Basicly I want to create a message box with three input fields under each other asking for "Name" "Surname" "Nickname". I also want to have the code really simple like:

```
name,surname,nick = askInfo("Name","Surname","Nickname")
```

It doesn't have to be wxPython but it MUST not be using Tkinter.

Answer (score 1):

Build a `wx.Dialog` there are numerous examples out there.

```
import wx
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "Dialog Test",size=(500,400))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.log = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, size=(400,300),style = wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY|wx.VSCROLL)
        self.button = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Click me")
        sizer.Add(self.log, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 10)
        sizer.Add(self.button, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 10)
        self.panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton)

    def OnButton(self,event):
        dlg = GetData(parent = self.panel) 
        dlg.ShowModal()
        if dlg.result_name:
            self.log.AppendText("Name: "+dlg.result_name+"\n")
            self.log.AppendText("Surname: "+dlg.result_surname+"\n")
            self.log.AppendText("Nickname: "+dlg.result_nickname+"\n")
        else:
            self.log.AppendText("No Input found\n")
        dlg.Destroy()

class GetData(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, "Name Input", size= (650,220))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self,wx.ID_ANY)

        self.lblname = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Name", pos=(20,20))
        self.name = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, value="", pos=(110,20), size=(500,-1))
        self.lblsur = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Surname", pos=(20,60))
        self.surname = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, value="", pos=(110,60), size=(500,-1))
        self.lblnick = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Nickname", pos=(20,100))
        self.nickname = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, value="", pos=(110,100), size=(500,-1))
        self.saveButton =wx.Button(self.panel, label="Save", pos=(110,160))
        self.closeButton =wx.Button(self.panel, label="Cancel", pos=(210,160))
        self.saveButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.SaveConnString)
        self.closeButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnQuit)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnQuit)
        self.Show()

    def OnQuit(self, event):
        self.result_name = None
        self.Destroy()

    def SaveConnString(self, event):
        self.result_name = self.name.GetValue()
        self.result_surname = self.surname.GetValue()
        self.result_nickname = self.nickname.GetValue()
        self.Destroy()

app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame(None)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Pay special attention to the `result` items